# Fossils of intermediate stages?

Tags: evolution

If Humans are evolve from Monkeys, there must be stages in the evolution process, when it was 1% human and 99% monkey, 2% human and 98% monkey  and so on. This is because evolution was a very slow process that occurred in a span of thousands of years. So we expect there must be fossils of this intermediate stages under earth. These intermediate-stage fossils must be many times in no. as compared to 100% human or 100% monkey.

But why do we do not discover these intermediate fossils?

Comment: Humans did not evolve from monkeys, we are apes (along with chimps, gorillas, and others).  We apes evolved from earlier primates, as did the monkeys and prosimians (like lemurs).

Comment: you have to remember that we are also getting further from our ape cousins all the time, even if we do not change into a new species.  Just the passage of time accumulates mutational differences between us and other species we are related to like the apes.

Comment: in addition to the comments above and the answer provided, note that we created the labels "monkey" and "human" based on the characters of these organisms.  There is no absolute "human" or "monkey" to partition into fractions.

Answer (score 13):

We do, all the time. Here's a nice graphic from Dr. Douglas Theobald. (Images copyright 2000 Smithsonian Institution.):

[image: Hominid fossils]

That's 14 Hominid species, ranging from about 4 M.Y. ago to a modern human skull ("N").

Here's a nice genealogy as well (although these change frequently as more evidence is gathered):

[image: Homo sapien geneology]